# ASP.NET MVC model binding vs nullable reference types

Tags: .net-6.0, c#-8.0, c#-10.0

I just created a new ASP.NET MVC application using .NET 6.0 and C# 10, and in this project template the Nullable Reference Types feature is enabled by default. But OK, I'm learning how to deal with this feature.

I had the following ViewModel class:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To avoid the Nullable Reference Type warning for the Name field, I created a constructor to initialize this field:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public CustomerViewModel(string name) => Name = name;

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But now, when I try to receive this ViewModel in my controller action, the binding mechanism asks for a parameterless constructor:

```
public IActionResult CreateCustomer(CustomerViewModel customer)
{
}
```

If I add a parameterless constructor to my ViewModel, I get the Nullable Reference Type warnings again, because the Name field will not have a initial value outside the constructor.

This field is non-nullable, so I can't make it nullable by adding a question mark operator. And for me it doesn't make sense to initialize this field with a "random" value, like String.Empty.

How are you dealing with this feature? Have you ever faced a scenario like this? And how did you solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the nature of model binding (first instantiate an object, then fill its properties), there is a conflict with the Nullable Reference Types feature. However, there is a good [blog post](https://www.stevenbenitez.com/nullable-reference-type-strategies/) which offers 3 ways of dealing with this:

1. Declare all fields as nullable and add a `[Required]` attribute

   ```
   [Required]
   public string? Name { get; set; }
   ```
2. Add the Null-forgiving operator to all non-nullable properties

   ```
   public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
   ```
3. Disable nullability warnings for the ViewModel

   ```
   #nullable disable warnings
   public class CustomerViewModel
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Just like the author of the blog, I prefer the third approach. Since the issue only occurs on classes that require a parameterless constructor, the nullable check can be disabled for these classes only. All properties remain uncluttered.

Comment: Hi, Bruno. Thank you for the answer. There is really a conflict of features here. For this project we chose the second aproach.